# Validation using navigation

Tags: asp.net

I have some pages in my website and a left menu control. Control helps to navigate from one page to another.

My query is -> While user try to navigate to another page, I want to impose some validation like in the current page if the form is not saved, user will be asked to save it by using a confirm messagebox and if user presses no button, then user will be allowed to navigate otherwise, system will first save the details and then navigate.

***Edit*** - My page is a content page, I meant, this is using a master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following steps

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

and a function that stops/continue the page execution.

```
 function confirmExit() {            
            var email= document.getElementById("email");
            if (email.value != "")
                return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
 }
```

Comment: I also want to call the save event of this page on clicking the yes button. please suggest how to do that.

Comment: I have also appended a line in my question.

Comment: just use the confirm function. e.g.  `if (confirm("Leave Page?")) {  
return true;
} else {  save();
return false;
} `

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to have an onbeforeunload javascript event fire which gives the user the choice to save the form. I personally would also poll the form saving data back whist they are completing it. I think this is the method SO uses.

There is a pretty decent example over on Code Project that may help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AutoSaveFormData.aspx

EDIT:

If you only want to call the save method you can mark it with the [WebMethod] filter and call it using XmlHttpRequest or jQuery's $.post

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it and will update you soon. Thanks.